# Can't run ant clean jar ide-dependencies command

Tags: java, ant, freemarker, ivy

I'm trying to setup Freemarker, but in order to be able to use it, I installed Ant (bin) and Ivy.

If I type ant -version everything seems fine, but everytime I type any command that involves ant, it displays "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed". I already copied the ivy jar file to the ant's lib folder. However, I'm still having the same problem.[image: Error msg]

Comment: Where is the build.xml file located?

Comment: There wasn't any build file when I extracted the ant files, do I have to create one?

Comment: Yes, see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_ant.html

Answer (score 1):

You should execute ant using `build.xml` file,

If you aren't in its directory, you can specify path using [-buildfile  or -file or -f](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

> -buildfile       use given buildfile
>
> -file                  ''
>
> -f                     ''

For example:

```
 ant -f c:\temp\build.xml clean jar ide-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to issue that command from FreeMarker's directory (the extracted FreeMarker source release directory, or where you have checked FreeMarker out from Git), not from the Ant directory. `build.xml` is part of the FreeMarker source code.